# how to add wrap Layout in scroll view dynamically

Tags: nativescript

i want to add wrap layout elements in scroll view dynamically using java script.
but when i try to add scroll view child it says, it is not a function.
i want to know is it possible to achieve this or not. 
one more thing is that i need to add layout by id i.e wrapId in below code.

```
<Page xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo">
    <Page.actionBar>
        <ActionBar title="Wrap Layout" />
    </Page.actionBar>
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout id="wrapId">

        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</Page>
```

**this is my xml and below is the js**

```
const WrapLayout = require("tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/wrap-layout").WrapLayout;
const StackLayout = require("tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/stack-layout").StackLayout;
var ScrollView = require('ui/scroll-view').ScrollView;
const Button = require("tns-core-modules/ui/button/").Button;

exports.onNavigatingTo = function (args) {
  const page = args.object;
  var wrapId = page.getViewById("wrapId");

  const myWrap = new WrapLayout();
  const myScroll = new ScrollView();

  myScroll.orientation = "vertical";

  for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    var button = `button${i}`;
    button = new Button();
    button.backgroundColor = "#0099CC";
    button.text = `${i}`;
    button.width = 150;
    button.height = 100;
    button.margin = 4;
    myWrap.addChild(button);
  }

  // myScroll.addChild(myWrap);
  page.content = myWrap;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollView` is just like `Page`, inherited from `ContentView` which supports holding only one child element. So it should be,

```
myScroll.content = myWrap;
```

Comment: can you kindly tell me is it possible to define layout by 'id'. i.e wrapId.content = mywrap like that.  is it possible to implement swipe gesture event and tap event. kindly  look here https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=UxckBN&v=4

Comment: Events must be added like this `myWrap.on("swipe", onSwipe)`. [Updated your Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=UxckBN&v=5).  You can define id by just `.id = YourId`. Once added to page, you can get that using `getViewById`.

Comment: no swipe not at all working. so i tried tap event on button and it worked perfectly but cannot read the text value on tap event. i need both, please do look here https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=UxckBN&v=6

Comment: Swipe doesn't work when ScrollView is wrapped, you have use swipe on ScrollView itself.

Comment: it works perfect, is it possible to mix xml. i.e i will create a stack layout and some labels in xml by normal code. then inside that stacklayout is it possible to create dynamic layout through javascript.